# how to read file with batch and use it in loop to write in temporary file

Tags: batch-file

I am using a batch script to open a file and create a temporary file. I reads text from a file and splits per lines. Then it's suppose to write into a temporary file, start firefox and open a link in it. Before the end of the loop it will delete the temporary file

```
taskkill /f /im "firefox.exe"

FOR /f "tokens=* delims=,"  %%i in (myfile.txt) do (
    @echo %%i
    @echo %%i > tmpkeywords.txt
    timeout 5


start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
timeout 10
ECHO Now running the macro (in a 2nd Tab)...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "wwww.google.com"

ECHO FINISHED!

timeout 60

REM REMOVE THE TEMPORARY FILE

del "C:\tmpkeywords.txt"

)
```

It doesn't do the job and has some error when it goes into the loop.

myfile.txt contains

```
something
something else
other thing
some other thing
```

Comment: Everything is in the same folder. The myfile.txt has keywords like I added in the post above.

Comment: I have no problems with file creation in C drIve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your batch code a little bit improved:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /f /im "firefox.exe"

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%i in (myfile.txt) do (
    echo %%i
    echo %%i>"%TEMP%\tmpkeywords.txt"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5
    start "" /B "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 10
    echo Now running the macro ^(in a 2nd tab^)...
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "wwww.google.com"

    echo FINISHED!

    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 60

    REM REMOVE THE TEMPORARY FILE

    del "%TEMP%\tmpkeywords.txt"
)
```

Important is to escape the parentheses in third echo command with `^` or otherwise `)` is interpreted as end of DO block.

And please note that with some characters listed on last help page output after entering in a command prompt window `cmd /?` in file **myfile.txt** this batch code would not work. Characters like

```
%<>&()[]{}^=;!'+`,~
```

have special meanings in batch syntax.

Therefore a batch code like below is perhaps better using delayed environment variable expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /f /im "firefox.exe"

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%i in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "Line=%%i"
    echo !Line!>"%TEMP%\tmpkeywords.txt"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5
    start "" /B "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 10
    echo Now running the macro ^(in a 2nd tab^)...
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "wwww.google.com"

    echo FINISHED!

    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 60

    REM REMOVE THE TEMPORARY FILE

    del "%TEMP%\tmpkeywords.txt"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Ok it works but it doesn't move on. It does only one keyword and doesn't do the others. The script just stays on this part. http://prntscr.com/5x3v13

Comment: __cmd.exe__ waits on termination of Firefox. You need to start Firefox also with command __start__ the second time. I have not understood the lines with __starting__ (first Firefox line) and __calling__ (second Firefox line) as not explained what Firefox really does here.

Comment: Okey I edited the batch script and added the code to start firefox. All is well now and batch script works fine. Thanks.